# Windows 8.1 scales WinForms app for no reason

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tablet

Figure this out and you'll be my programming hero:

My client uses a Surface Pro tablet running on Windows 8.1
The app is a desktop app based on WinForms.

When the app tries to open a TIFF image, and only then, Windows will decide to scale up the application (what's called Display Scaling) and the result is everything in the app suddenly looks so small that you can't see or work with it at all. So we want to avoid that scaling. (And turning it off from the Compatibility tab is even worse)

Now is the fun part. The code looks like this:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));

// At this point the app looks ok...
bitmap = LoadTiffFromStream(stream);

private static Bitmap LoadTiffFromStream(Stream stream)
{
// Here before any code executes, the app is scaled
```

As you can see, we load some file into a stream, we pass the stream to a method, and before any code of the method is executed, the app is scaled. This happens only for TIFF images, as if the app somehow knows the stream contains TIFF data!

Some tests:

1. Same code put in empty test app does not produce the same behavior
2. The TIFF file is not bigger or smaller than other files that are loaded fine, and it is not related to stream size, file name nor any file system permissions
3. I have verified no other code is executed between those two lines
4. It happens absolutely every time, only for TIFF images, for any TIFF image and before any code that has anything to do with the TIFF format is executed (I just send a stream to a method!)

I can't figure it out. Can you?

Comment: Does using [Solution 2: Disable display scaling for the app](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/apps-and-windows-store/app-display-issues?lc=1033#Solution2) help?

Comment: I haven't tested this specific problem, but the whole UI gets totally screwed when I disable display scaling, so this is not an option for us.

Answer (score -1):

Have you experimented with different ways of loading the image?

```
Bitmap img = Image.FromFile(@"MyImage.tif").Clone() as Bitmap;
```